# Cannot SSH on to AWS EC2 instance created using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

I have been creating AWS EC2 instances using Ubuntu and Boto for months. They start-up, I issue commands from Python etc. This has been working fine.

I create the instances using this:

```
instances = ec2.create_instances(
            ImageId=image_id,
            MinCount=1,
            MaxCount=num_instances,
            InstanceType=instance_type,
            IamInstanceProfile={ 'Name': 'SSMInstanceProfile' },
            Placement={'AvailabilityZone': availability_zone}
```

Today I created and downloaded a private key file from EC2 console. I then created another instance using Boto (exactly how I have been doing previously).

I got the public DNS address from the console and tried to ssh on to it from my local machine using:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4.region.compute.amazonaws.com
```

etc

Nothing happened, the command line just hung.

Do I need to change how I create my boto instances, to accept the new `.pem` key file?

If not, do I need to change something in the EC2 console to map `SSMInstanceProfile` to be SSH'd using that `.pem`?

Comment: You seem to be relying on the default VPC and its default security group. Have you checked the latter to ensure it allows inbound SSH?

Comment: @jarmod I don't understand much about this. Do I just need to Google how to enable SSH for the default VPC?

Comment: I'm assuming this EC2 instance was launched in VPC, not in the legacy [EC2-Classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html), so it will be in the default VPC with its [default security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-security-group.html). Identify which VPC that is then review the ingress rules for the security group (basically firewall settings). Add them to your post.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you didn't supply an SSH key pair via `KeyName` when launching the instance so you won't be able to SSH to the instance unless you chose an AMI that is pre-configured with a keypair (which would be unusual). Supply the relevant keypair name and launch a new instance. Also check the security group rules for SSH ingress but I presume they're not the main issue.

Comment: @jarmod Right so my key file is MyKeyFile.pem and so I need to pass an additional parameter `KeyName="MyKeyFile"` in to `create_instances()`?

Comment: @jarmod Unfortunately my previous comment doesn't seem to have solved it

Comment: It's not the filename of the .PEM file. It's the configured key pair name in EC2. It might be the same, but it doesn't have to be. Navigate to key pairs in the EC2 console and find the key pair name associated with the PEM file that you have. Or add a new key pair, supplying the content of the PEM file, and use that name.

Comment: @jarmod I've just checked, name and file name were the same anyway. Does this mean  your initial suggestion is what i should check next? I can see the instance's SecurityGroup is the `default` one.

Comment: Just checking the security group rules....

Comment: @jarmod Default security group allows all traffic, all ports, all protocols

Comment: I'd recommend [Troubleshoot connecting to your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html). BTW that all/all/all rule sounds more like a default outbound rule than inbound rule.

Comment: @jarmod Just going through  but it seems I have a lot setup. Does it narrow down the problem if I can connect through the Session Manager successfully?

Comment: No, Session Manager doesn't require incoming ports configured.  You almost certainly don't have a rule for SSH in your security group setup.  That said, if you can connect via Session Manager, why not use that instead of direct SSH?

Comment: @AnonCoward I need to SCP a binary across. Is there another way of doing this? (genuine question)

Comment: You can use [tunneling via ProxyCommand](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/session-manager-launches-tunneling-support-for-ssh-and-scp/), which will allow you to use a traditional ssh client, and a scp client through the SSM tunnel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When attempting to SSH into an Amazon EC2 instance, a 'hanging' response indicates that your SSH client was unable to connect to the instance. (If it did connect, but the connection was refused, the error would appear immediately.)

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone) -- presumably this is fine since you previously connected to an instance

Most times, the problem is related to the **Security Group**. Instead of using the Default security group, I recommend that you **create a new Security Group** with:

- An **Inbound rule** permitting SSH from your IP address (more secure than allowing from Anywhere)
- An **Outbound rule** permitting all outbound traffic to Anywhere (`0.0.0.0/0`)

Or, instead of attempting to connect via SSH, you could use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager. Please note that this requires some permissions to be added to the IAM Role associated with the EC2 instance. See: [Add instance permissions for Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-instance-profile.html)

Comment: Hi John, unfortunately if you glance at this question i've checked all of those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681591/cannot-ssh-in-to-aws-ec2-instance-includes-screenshots-of-all-settings-checked

Comment: Well, apparently something isn't configured as you assume since you are unable to SSH into the instance. Try launching another instance in the EC2 console using the same subnet and security group and see if you can connect. If so, it's then a matter of comparing the differences.

Comment: I've done that. I've been creating new instances each time I've tried. I only have the one Security Group and one VPC (neither of which I have changed from the default AWS settings).

Comment: Rather than using the Default security group, try creating a new Security Group with port 22 (SSH) open to your IP address or to `0.0.0.0/0`. Then, associate the security group with the EC2 instance. Also, make sure you are connecting to the Public IP of the instance -- it should not start with `10.` or `172.`

Comment: Works. Very impressed. But why does this work when my default SG had rules allowing ssh?

Comment: It's difficult to answer that without seeing the configuration of the Default security group. Presumably, it wasn't configured as you expected.

Comment: I think I might know what is the cause. In my default SG, for the incoming rule it says any ports and protocols. However, the IP version field has a "-" whereas the new SG has "IPv4"?